# Sonar ant task fails with Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl not found exception

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to run sonar ant task on Bamboo machine. The same task works fine on my local machine (ant version 1.9.3 as well as ant version 1.8.2) but fails on bamboo ant 1.8.2 with following error

```
    org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
    at org.sonar.ant.SonarTask.launchAnalysis(SonarTask.java:53)
    at org.sonar.ant.SonarTask.execute(SonarTask.java:48)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
    error   15-Aug-2014 16:08:20    Caused by: javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl not found
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance(SAXParserFactory.java:134)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.event.SaxEventRecorder.buildSaxParser(SaxEventRecorder.java:81)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.event.SaxEventRecorder.recordEvents(SaxEventRecorder.java:59)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:134)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:99)
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.initLogging(IsolatedLauncher.java:71)
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.createBatch(IsolatedLauncher.java:52)
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
    ... 24 more
```

I have tried putting xercesImpl.jar in ant classpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue running sonarqube 4.2 where findbugs would fail due to the missing parser. I was able to solve the issues by placing the xercesImpl.jar in the [sonar.home]/web/WEB-INF/lib folder and restarting the server. Once all other dependency issues were resolved by placing other needed jars in the same location, the issue disappeared.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this soon and let you know.

Comment: When I put xercesImpl.jar in that folder the sonar doesn't start at all.

Comment: I was finally able to resolve it by putting xml-apis.jar in addition to xercesImpl.jar in the above mentioned folder. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue, also using Bamboo and the sonar Ant task.

I found that it was because I had run ant with an old java version. I switched from 1.6 to 1.7 and the issue was resolved.

Hope this helps someone in the future.